# LaTeX: separate columns in a table with a character instead of a line

Tags: tables

Is it practically possible to use a character to separate the columns of a table instead of a vertical line?

Specifically consider a two column table, with col1 and col2. As long as col1 is a single line there is no problem. The problem occurs when col1 is a long line and word wraps into multiple lines (still one row, of course). The character `(` a close parens, `)` in this case) appears between the columns on the first displayed line as it should but not on the subsequent lines.

I need it to appear on all the displayed lines.

My suspicion is the normal vertical line is drawn graphically and is not a repeated character so the answer is no and the long line must be manually broken into multiple rows but it would certainly be useful if there were a reasonable way (without rewriting the system, of course) to have LaTeX do it automatically.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{!{(}p{1cm}!{)}!{(}p{1cm}!{)}}
    col1 & col2 \\ 
    long text 1 & long text 2 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since your question is very interesting, I took the liberty to add a MWE, please rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: it is rather hard to define what you mean by "line" here (and latex doesn't try) the table row is larger than the `)` but that doesn's necessarily relate to lines of text in a `p` column,  you would see the same if the cell had a large image,  or `\\[1cm]` was used for the end of row, or the table was expanded with `\arraystretch` or `\extrarowheight`

Comment: Line refers to lines of display. For example assume a text line of 'one two three four' is word wrapped between the two and three, it would appear as two display lines although it is only one line. A text line of 'one two\\ three four' would also appear on two display lines but would in fact be two lines and would be treated as such.

Comment: To address another user you have to type @ followed by the nickname, in your case @DavidCarlisle. Otherwise he could not see your comment.

Comment: It might be possible to do it with strechable math parentheses, so that the parentheses don't just span one row and are repeated, but span two or three rows in case a cell is broken over several rows. This way, the parentheses would also indicate the height of the cell. Not like I would be able to implement that, it's just an idea, but if someone with the skillz reads this, I guess: knock yourself out.

Answer (score 1):

I have some doubts regarding a pure latex solution. But with lualatex you could do this:

```
%needs lualatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\localleftbox{%
       \llap{\makebox[2\tabcolsep]{(}}%
       \rlap{\hspace{1cm}\makebox[1\tabcolsep]{)}}}}p{1cm}
                >{\localleftbox{%
       \llap{\makebox[2\tabcolsep]{(}}%
       \rlap{\hspace{1cm}\makebox[1\tabcolsep]{)}}}}p{1cm}
               }
    col1 & col2 \\
    long text 1 & long text 2 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I can't evaluate at the moment because of problems with installation. I am reinstalling texlive and will check back when new installation is up and running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=),      
        text width=1cm,
        text height=1ex
    }
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix{
            \node[mynode] {col 1};&
            \node[mynode] {col 2};\\
            \node[mynode] {long text 1};&
            \node[mynode] {long text 2};\\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there is a better solution, see Kpym's answer here: [Different behavior of matrix with node defined explicitly with delimeters versus matrix of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433905/different-behavior-of-matrix-with-node-defined-explicitly-with-delimeters-versus).