# Different behavior of matrix with node defined explicitly with delimeters versus matrix of nodes

Tags: errors, tikz-matrix

While I was trying to answer [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433464/latex-separate-columns-in-a-table-with-a-character-instead-of-a-line) I found out that `matrix of nodes` gives the error: `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].` when the nodes have delimiters.

It doesn't happen whit a `matrix` with nodes defined explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=),      
        text width=1cm
    }
}
\begin{document}
    Why this works:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix{
            \node[mynode] {long text 1};&
            \node[mynode] {long text 2};\\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    whereas this one gives \texttt{! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].}:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={mynode}]{
         long text 1 &
         long text 2 \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    ?
\end{document}
```

Please note that I would like the second matrix of my example gives the same result as the first, with the delimiters around every cell, not around the whole matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in general you can't add `left delimiter` or right `right delimiter` in `every node` style because internally the delimiters add a node, so this create an infinite loop. You can check this in this simple example that throws also `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={left delimiter=(}]
    \node {Some text here};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To overcome this you can hack the (or submit a bug request) `\tikz@delimiter` by resetting `every node` style before the internal node creation, like this :

```
\def\tikz@delimiter#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \bgroup
    \pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@fig@name=\tikz@last@fig@name\tikzset{every node/.style={}}}% <-- added reset `every node` style
    node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,anchor=#1,at=(\tikz@last@fig@name.#2),#3]
    {%
      {\nullfont\pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#4}}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#5}}}}%
      $\left#6\vcenter{\hrule height .5#8 depth .5#8 width0pt}\right#7$%
    }
    \pgfextra{\global\let\tikz@last@fig@name=\tikz@save@last@fig@name}%
  \egroup%
}
```

So there is no more error in my first code :

```
\def\tikz@delimiter#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \bgroup
    \pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@fig@name=\tikz@last@fig@name\tikzset{every node/.style={}}}% <-- added reset `every node` style
    node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,anchor=#1,at=(\tikz@last@fig@name.#2),#3]
    {%
      {\nullfont\pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#4}}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#5}}}}%
      $\left#6\vcenter{\hrule height .5#8 depth .5#8 width0pt}\right#7$%
    }
    \pgfextra{\global\let\tikz@last@fig@name=\tikz@save@last@fig@name}%
  \egroup%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={left delimiter=(}]
    \node {Some text here};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And so your code works too.

```
%
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@delimiter#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \bgroup
    \pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@fig@name=\tikz@last@fig@name\tikzset{every node/.style={}}}% <-- added reset `every node` style
    node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,anchor=#1,at=(\tikz@last@fig@name.#2),#3]
    {%
      {\nullfont\pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#4}}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#5}}}}%
      $\left#6\vcenter{\hrule height .5#8 depth .5#8 width0pt}\right#7$%
    }
    \pgfextra{\global\let\tikz@last@fig@name=\tikz@save@last@fig@name}%
  \egroup%
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=),
        text width=1cm
    }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={mynode}]{
         long text 1 &
         long text 2 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]